# Creating Group From SalesForce

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, list

In my mind, the ideal situation in Marketing Cloud would be to have no lists but only groups pulling from SalesForce. We keep track of the newsletters our users subscribe to in SalesForce, so we have the information.

Is it possible to create a group in MC that pulls from SF? Or at worst, can we create a list in MC that pulls from SF and then create groups from that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Marketing Cloud Connector, it is possible to send to a Salesforce Report which is basically the same idea as a Marketing Cloud group.  It evaluates the report at the time of send so it would have the most up-to-date information from SalesForce.